# Javascript discount shopping cart

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart, discount

I am having trouble getting a discount to work on this Javascript file.  I am trying to have it apply a discount if the cart is a certain amount for example- Discount $20 off orders over $50.

```
function totalCost(product, action) {
let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
var discount20 = parseInt(cartCost) - 20
var discount50 = parseInt(cartCost) - 50

console.log("My cartCost is", cartCost);
console.log(typeof cartCost );

if (cartCost == 50) {
    cartCost = discount20
} else if (cartCost == 200){
    cartCost = discount50
};

if( action == "decrease") {
    cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);

    localStorage.setItem('totalCost',cartCost - product.price);
} else if(cartCost != null) {
    cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.price);
} else {
    localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
}
}
```

**EDIT: This is what I ended up doing**

```
function totalCost(product, action) {
    let cartCost = localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    // VARIABLES FOR 20 OR 50
    var discount20 = parseInt(cartCost) - 20
    var discount50 = parseInt(cartCost) - 50
    
    console.log("My cartCost is", cartCost);
    console.log(typeof cartCost );

    // DISCOUNT FUNCTIONALITY
    if (cartCost >= 50 || cartCost <= 75) {
        cartCost = discount20
        console.log('discount 20!', cartCost = discount20)
    } else if (cartCost >= 200 || cartCost <= 250){
        cartCost = discount50
        console.log('discount 50!', cartCost = discount50)
    };

    if( action == "decrease") {
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost)
        localStorage.setItem('totalCost',cartCost - product.price);
    } else if(cartCost != null) {
        cartCost = parseInt(cartCost);
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", cartCost + product.price);
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem("totalCost", product.price);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change to line no: 5    if (cartCost >= 50) {

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that!

Comment: if you have any issues or bug fixes on your code. you can direct contact via my profile as: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8308674/mujahid-bhoraniya